# Python draw graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a text file that consists of 3 columns.

1. column contain X coordinate
2. column contain Y coordinate
3. column contain 0 or 1

So far I draw all the coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt("coordinates.txt",delimiter=' ',skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1),unpack=True)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I want to draw only those coordinates where the value of 2rd column is 1.

Please help me.

Comment: You will need to *read* all three columns; and filter the rows based on the third column; then plot the result. There are many ways to do that.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

hope this help:

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np

   f = np.loadtxt('coordinates.txt',delimiter=' ',skiprows=1)

   f = f[f[:,2] == 1]
   x = f[:,0]
   y = f[:,1]
   plt.plot([x], [y], 'ro')
   plt.show()
```

Comment: Consider explaining why this answer works. Giving insights is also good for futures users. _try this_ or _hope this help_ is rarely a good enough answer.

Comment: @tiperos, there is a type conversion error, string instead of float; try to verify your data-source.

Comment: How verify ? :(

Answer (score 0):

The long way to do this is using a loop that plots (lets say) dots based on position within the list. But it might be a helpful to you, considering your comments. 
Based on your comments, the data you're dealing with is considered as a *string*. Be sure to check types of data if you're planing to deal with programming. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('coordinates.txt',delimiter=' ',skiprows=1)
x_data = data[:,0] # [every row, "1st" column]
y_data = data[:,1] # [every row, "2nd" column]
z_data = data[:,2] # [every row, "3rd" column]

#check every number in z and if it is equal to your desired condition, 
#plot blue circle ('bo') on coordinates where that condition is satisfied (x[i], y[i])
for i in range(len(z)):
if z[i] == str(1):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i], 'bo')
```

You can also plot every dot, and make them different like this:

```
for i in range(len(z)):
if z[i] == str(1):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i], 'bo') #ones are blue dots
else:
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i], 'ro') #zeros are red dots
```

I would definitely recommend that you do some research on how to read data and how to deal with it when it's read (for example: converting strings to floats), because this is not the proper way to do this, but it will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont know convert :( Please, will you write it to me?